# Distinguishing Between Words and Numbers in a String - Assertion Error

Tags: python

```
def checkio(words):
    word = words.isalpha()
    num = words.isdigit()
    if word:
        pass
    if num:
        pass
    return True or False


print checkio(u"Hello World hello") == True, "Hello"
print checkio(u"He is 123 man") == False, "123 man"
print checkio(u"1 2 3 4") == False, "Digits"
print checkio(u"bla bla bla bla") == True, "Bla Bla"
print checkio(u"Hi") == False, "Hi"
```

It works fine. But -

1. When I replace print with assert, it gives Assertion Error. How do I OKAY that?
2. This is a puzzle that requires the use of .split() to solve it. I can't figure out how to use it, because when I convert it to list .isdigit and isalpha won't work. Need help.

Thanks!

Note - This is what the puzzle page says -

"Precondition: The input contains words and/or numbers. There are no mixed words (letters and digits combined).
0 < |words| < 100 (This is a simple task)." I ain't following this line.

Comment: What is `return True or False` supposed to do?

Comment: output whether the string contains only words or numbers. If words, True. If numbers, False.

Comment: `True or False` evaluates to `True`, so you are trying to `assert True == False` in some cases, which of course will not be the case.

Comment: You are given a string with words and numbers separated by whitespaces (one space). The words contains only letters. You should check if the string contains three words in succession - That is the instruction.

Comment: Thanks for the down vote, whoever it was. Have mercy on a noob.

Comment: @UmmMaryam: So it's this [problem](http://www.checkio.org/mission/three-words/)?

Comment: Yes GWW. That is the one.

Comment: "It works fine. But - " no, it does not. It does not do anything and always returns true. The assignment says "You should check if the string contains three words in succession". You don't do that.

Comment: @ 2rs2ts. I am partly following you, just can't figure out how the code should be.

Comment: @ tobaise, yea, I figured that. 'print' key fooled me.

Comment: How does .split play it's part?

Comment: You split the words to get a list of individual words, then use a loop to count the number of successive alphabetic words. You know about loops, do you?

Comment: Consider reading the documentation on [sequence types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange), particularly [string methods](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods).

Comment: Yea, I know while and for loops. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To just address the one function you have so far:

```
def checkio(words):
    word = words.isalpha() # word = either True or False
    num = words.isdigit()  # num = either True or False
    if word: # these four
        pass # lines don't
    if num:  # actually
        pass # do anything
    return True or False # always evaluates to return True
```

You never actually *use* the variables `word` and `num` you create at the start of the function (aside to determine whether to `pass` explicitly or implicitly), which should give you a good idea that your function probably isn't doing much!

A few snippets to help you:

```
words = words.split() # get list of individual words

len(words) # how many words

for word in words: # iterate through the words
```

You could keep a running count of how many alphabetic words you have seen in a row, and `return True` if it gets to three.

Comment: You misunderstood the question. Its not that there are exactly three alphabetic words and nothing else, but at least three alphabetic words in a row.

Comment: @tobias_k It's not his fault - the question doesn't even state that, and the OP said two different things in the comments.

Comment: I did not say that it's anyone's fault. Its in the assignment linked by GWW and also can be seen from the examples. (BTW, +1, now with the new final sentence)

Answer (score 0):

### Using `.split()`

As you have already realized, `.split()` turns a string into a list of strings. By default, it will separate the string into its whitespace-delimited parts.

```
>>> "Hello World hello".split()
['Hello', 'World', 'hello']
```

Obviously, `.isalpha()` and `.isdigit()` are methods of strings, not lists. So you have to iterate through the strings inside your list, and check whether each is a word or number.

```
>>> for word in "Hello World hello".split():
        if word.isalpha(): print "word!"
        elif word.isdigit(): print "digit!"


word!
word!
word!
```

Now that you know how to go about checking each word, it is up to you to figure out how to determine if the string contains three words in succession.

### Your `AssertionError`s

Now, the reason why you had `AssertionError`s was what you were returning with `return True or False`. Look:

```
>>> True or False
True
```

This means you are always returning `True`. Unfortunately this is [simple boolean arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Operations) so you need to read up on it. I think you were trying to say "this function will either return `True`, or return `False`," but that is not at all what you expressed. Anyway, if you replace this `print` statement with an `assert`:

```
print checkio(u"He is 123 man") == False
# goes to
assert checkio(u"He is 123 man") == False
```

You are saying `assert True == False`, hence the error. Try returning `True` if you can find three words in succession, and `False` otherwise.